# Using 'sed' find and replace some text and store it in another file

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, sed

I have a file base_foo.txt and want to replace some text in the base_file and store it in another file without altering the base file. Thanks!

Something like:

```
sed -i -e 'r/foo/bar/' base_foo.txt ???
```

Comment: do not use `-i` option in your command and use redirection operator to send it to other file.,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the onriginal file, you have to remove the `-i` flag. Without `-i` `sed` will send its output to `stdout`, so you'll to redirect it to a file. Just do something like that:

```
sed -e 'r/foo/bar/' base_foo.txt > new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`-i`  is in place replacement in sed. So it its used original file would be modified.

To display changes use :

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' file  #Only to stdout
```

Redirecting changes to to new file :

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' file > new.file # changes would be only in new.file
```

To make changes in orignal keeping backup

```
sed  -i.bak -e 's/foo/bar/g' file  #Changes in file ,no change in file.bak
```